# How can I Use query to pull information from another google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

HI I have two google spreadsheets one spread sheet has multiple tabs with various information. The second spread sheet is a master data list of patients names and correlating information. As of now I  have the mater data tab that i pull this information from. I would just like to simply move it to a separate sheet spreadsheet. This is the formula I use to pull data from the data tab (FC). =IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(CHAR(10),QUERY(FC!$A$2:F,"Select D Where B='"&A21&"'"))))

How do I move tab FC to its own spreadsheet and get the same outcome on this sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LACispsI59c4plpX1RmlTfugJE7rz8mRSgW4K1Uiw-E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rqz_z4iqfapiHQdHi4zJvWWl4Y1A-xbVHJRIH9MSouU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

If you separate the master sheet, you will have to import data from the slave spreadsheets using `IMPORTRANGE('ID of the source',sheet1!A2:F)` for instance and then apply query on it. Give a link to a simplified mockup.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet's_url", "FC!A2:F"), 
 "select Col4 
  where Col2='"&A21&"'"))))
```

example:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BhBUDx9LKKQIC2zQbDM2IOhVAV6ppygbts2vT-NmhAM/edit#gid=0", "data!A1:F"), 
 "select Col4 
  where Col1='"&A1&"'"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! but I cannot seem to get the data to show up

Comment: @EmmaBourdeau answer updated. see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BhBUDx9LKKQIC2zQbDM2IOhVAV6ppygbts2vT-NmhAM/edit#gid=0

Comment: what does the first number 1 mean after (char10)?

Comment: @EmmaBourdeau it means to join all cells excluding empty cells. its a prevention so you wouldnt end up with joined string that has multiple commas in a row like `abc,,,def,,xx,cc,,,,,,,,,,hjk` (or in your case `CHAR(10)` instead of commas)